# Python httplib.HTTPSConnection import error

Tags: python, mysql, httplib, mysql-connector-python

I am using MySQL Connector/Python to insert something in a database and it works perfectly fine when I run it from the linux console (Ubuntu), but when I try and execute the script from a web page, I get the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named xmlrpc.client 
      args = ('No module named xmlrpc.client',) 
      message = 'No module named xmlrpc.client'
```

So I did some digging and found this in connection.py (where the error occurs):

```
try:
    from xmlrpclib import Fault, ServerProxy, Transport
    import urllib2
    from httplib import HTTPSConnection, BadStatusLine
except ImportError:
    # Python v3
    from xmlrpc.client import Fault, ServerProxy, Transport
    import urllib.request as urllib2
    from http.client import HTTPSConnection, BadStatusLine
```

I am using Python 2.7 so it shouldn't go on the `except` branch and yet it does. After some testing, I found that the `ImportError` occurs at `from http.client import HTTPSConnection` but couldn't find a reason for why that happens or how I can fix it.

Comment: Could you please show us the error message when you execute from httplib import HHTPConnection  ? What if you re-install the latest httplib package?

Comment: It says "Cannot import name HTTPSConnection"

Comment: I think you have a httplib.py in the same or father directory so that Python standard httplib library doesn't take effect.

Comment: Is there a possibility for this to happen if I didn't create any httplib.py ?

Comment: You can put your connection.py to another folder, for instance, '/'. Then execute again to check if this error still exists. If so, there must be something with your httplib package. If not, you must create your own httplib.py file in your legacy folder.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the error happens when I run the script through CGI in Apache. If I move connection.py to another folder, wouldn't that make it impossible to import connection.py?

Comment: Sorry, when I said connection.py I mean the code between the try and except block. Will there be errors when you don't run the script through CGI in Apache?

Comment: It works good when I run it from console as "python scriptname.py".